# Select single minimum value of Pandas dataframe column instead multiple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min, minimum

I want get minimum value a year from a dataframe(**df_greater_TDS**) column('**DTS38**').
So I grouped by **year**-column and applied transform(min). However, as there are multiple minimum values, min function is returning multiple rows.

how to get only one value or here a single row?

```
idx = df_greater_TDS.groupby('year')['DTS38'].transform(min)==df_greater_TDS['DTS38']
df_TDS=df_greater_TDS[idx]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `df.loc[df.groupby('year')['DTS38'].idxmin()]`.

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution was pretty close `df[df['DTS38'] == df.groupby('year')['DTS38'].transform('min')]`